# Python version in vscode is set to 2.7 while 3.7 is supposed to be running. How to fix the workspace and user settings to make it work?

Tags: python

I have selected the python 3.7 interpreter but even after doing that the vscode terminal is still running `python 2.7`. How do I make my terminal run `python 3.7` instead. I've tried several methods, none of them have been successful.

I've tried overriding the user and workspace settings in the `json` file of `vscode` but I'm not able to edit the default workspace and user settings.

```
import sys; print(sys.version)
```

O/P:

```
Ashwins-MacBook-Pro:blockchain ashwin$ python test.py
2.7.10 (default, Aug 17 2018, 19:45:58)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.0.42)]

Expected: 

Ashwins-MacBook-Pro:blockchain ashwin$ python test.py
3.7 (default, Aug 17 2018, 19:45:58)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.0.42)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the python extensions in VScode marketplace? There will be some conflicts between the python extensions and the VScode terminal. Try to uninstall the extensions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30889382)

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the correct interpreter in your settings. Just follow [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Comment: I did set the correct interpreter but my terminal still runs python 2.7. I am not able to change the default settings in the json file.

Comment: @Ashwin Did you open a new terminal window in vscode after selecting the correct interpreter?

Comment: I did! The version is still in 2.7 instead of 3.7.

Comment: The docs do not explain how to do this. It is possible somehow, but it seems complex having to use an extension, but I've not got this working yet, it is really annoying.

Answer (score -1):

The `python` command is defined as Python 2 **unless** you are using an activated virtual environment. Selecting the Python interpreter in the Python extension for VS Code does not redefine what `python` points to.

To bring up Python 3.7 in the terminal you should use the `python3.7` command.

Comment: I did that but I'm not able the execute my file when I use the 'python3.7' command.

Comment: @Ashwin then that will be due to an issue with your system as the extension does not affect the commands run in your terminal. If `python3.7` is not available then it's not on your `PATH` and you need to fix that.